# C# - Connecting reference to previously created instance?

Tags: c#, class, object, reference

For example, I've created the following code:

```
class Info
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Age;
    }

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Info APersonsAccount;
        APersonsAccount = new Info();
        
        APersonsAccount.Name = "NameOfPerson";
        APersonsAccount.Age = 23;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0,-15} Age: {1,-20}", APersonsAccount.Name, APersonsAccount.Age);
        
        APersonsAccount = new Info();
        
        APersonsAccount.Name = "OtherName";
        APersonsAccount.Age = 25;
        
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0,-15} Age: {1,-20}", APersonsAccount.Name, APersonsAccount.Age);
    }
}
```

I now want `APersonsAccount` to refer to the first instance of type `Info` I created. Is there any way to go about this or would the solution be to just create a new instance exactly same as the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing `APersonsAccount = new Info();` the second time, you're overwriting the  reference stored in `APersonsAccount`.
If you want to still have a reference to the first `Info` instance you created, simply store it in a different variable.
E.g.

```cs
Info AccountInfo1 = new Info();
Info AccountInfo2 = new Info();
```

Comment: Or maybe use a collection to store the instances, as a `List<Info>`.